# Alert stops scripts

Tags: javascript, alert, execution

I'm trying to have an alert showing while my script runs in the background but it seems like alerts are made to stop everything on the site. Is there any way of preventing this and making the script run while the alert is showing? Function: `function jobbig()
{
alert("JOBBIGT");
}`

Code i want to run while the alert is showing: `

```
     }
     function changez() {
     if(y == 1) {
         colour = "red";
         y = 2;
         }
         else if(y == 2)
         {
         colour = "green";
         y = 3;
         }
         else if(y == 3)
         {
         colour = "black";
         y = 4;
         }
         else if(y == 4)
         {
         colour = "yellow";
         y = 5;
         }
         else if(y == 5)
         {
         colour = "cyan";
         y = 6;
         }
         else if(y == 6)
         {
         colour = "white";
         y = 1;
         }

document.getElementById("head").style.color = colour;
}`
```

```
function change()    {
       if(x == 1) {
         color = "black";
         x = 2;
         }
         else if(x == 2)
         {
         color = "white";
         x = 3;
         }
         else if(x == 3)
         {
         color = "yellow";
         x = 4;
         }
         else if(x == 4)
         {
         color = "red";
         x = 5;
         }
         else if(x == 5)
         {
         color = "green";
         x = 6;
         }
         else if(x == 6)
         {
         color = "cyan";
         x = 7;
         }
         else if(x == 7)
         {
         color = "purple";
         x = 1;
         }
        else if(x == 1337)
        {
        color = "white";
        }
 document.body.style.background = color; }
```

The code is ran by `function andrafarg30() {
        clearInterval(interval2);
        clearInterval(interval3);
        clearInterval(intervall2);
        clearInterval(intervall3);
         x = 1;
         y = 1;
         interval1 = setInterval(change, 30);
         intervall1 = setInterval(changez, 45);
     }`which is called by a button. The alert is also called by a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message) component with `modal: true` option instead of Window.alert function.

Do the following:

1. Put the reference to the jQuery UI to the header of you site
   `<script
   src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>` after
   jquery.js inlude.
2. change `function jobbig() { alert("JOBBIGT"); }` to `function jobbig() { var tag = $('<div>JOBBIGT</div>'); tag.dialog({modal: true}); }`

If you need somehow customize the dialog, please see the [demo](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/).

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jQuery so i dont know how to compile that with my own code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a non-blocking `alert` may be a bad idea, especially in a loop, but is possible. The easiest way to achieve it is to run it through something else that is non-blocking, for example `setTimeout`

```
function makeNonBlocking(func, context) {
    if (!context) context = null;
    return function () {
        var args = arguments;
        setTimeout(function () {func.apply(context, args)}, 0);
    };
}
var myAlert = makeNonBlocking(alert);

myAlert('foo');
console.log('bar'); // appears before user okays `foo` alert
myAlert('baz');
```

Why don't you consider a `console.log` instead, though?

Comment: I dont understand what you've done in your code, can someone please explain it? Thanks

Comment: I tried to be as generic as possible; `makeNonBlocking` is a _function_ which returns a new _function_. The new _function_ wraps the _function_ given as the first parameter of `makeNonBlocking`, invoking it through a `setTimeout`. I use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to carry forward any `arguments` passed into the new _function_. I then invoke `makeNonBlocking` with `alert` to generate a non-blocking version of `alert`, which I go on to use.

Comment: If you understood all that then next, if you'll be working with a changing `this`, you may also want a bit more logic for `context` and capture `this` at the same time as I `var args`.